# How to set which hue on top(overlap) in scatter plot in seaborn

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have below scatter plot A and B, Let's say I want to make my A on top of B,
How to make my A plot on top? I've tried other tips but seems not giving me my desire output

```
            df_Scatter = pd.read_excel ('Scatter.xlsx')
            ax = sns.scatterplot (x = "X_Label", y = "Y_Label", hue = 'Type', palette = ['orange', 'dodgerblue'], data = df_Scatter)
            ax.set_xlabel ('X_Label')
            ax.set_ylabel ('Y_Label')
            ax.set_title ('X vs Y')
            ax.set (xlim = (-10, 30), ylim = (0, 160))
            plt .grid (color = 'gray', linestyle = '-', linewidth = 0.5)
            plt.show ()
```

Output[]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AV2Q.png

I've tried using hue_order but it only arrange my legend not the plots

```
            ax = sns.scatterplot (x = "X_Label", y = "Y_Label", hue = 'Type', hue_order=['B','A'], palette = ['dodgerblue','orange'], data = df_Scatter)
```

Output[]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/swH1K.png

For my interim solution I tag my hue by number so I can choose which one I can put on top.

```
    df_Scatter.loc[df_Scatter['Type'] == 'A', 'Top'] = 1
    df_Scatter.loc[df_Scatter['Type'] == 'B', 'Top'] = 2
    df_Scatter = df_Scatter.sort_values(by=['Top'], ascending=True)
```

If there's any way much better I will appreciate

Comment: I realise now what you were asking, and I'm not sure how to do it so I've deleted my answer. I'll look for information about how to do this, and get back to you if I find anything.

Comment: I have modified my question, I added my interim solution. But if there's any way much better. I appreciate. thanks

Comment: Your solution is actually pretty good and easy to implement, at least in my case !